# Stopping a thread immediately as second thread want access

Tags: java, multithreading

"I have a XYZ class in that I have written two methods A and B, Now two threads are operating on one the objects of this class, One thread is in the A method, I want that as soon as second thread calls my B method, thread in method A should immediately stop and come out. Would anybody tell me the solution for this?"

Comment: So you want your data structures to be corrupted as soon as there's a race condition? Oh that's easy: Remove all locks. More seriously: You're quite certainly solving the wrong problem: More context.

Comment: I think you didn't get my  point I want to stop the first thread as soon as second tries to enter

Comment: There is no problem sharing methods as they don't change (or you don't see them change ;) the problem is only sharing mutable data. I wouldn't worry about what threads are running which methods, instead worry about when shared data is being changed.

Comment: @SunnyGupta We don't understand why you would want to do that. Can you explain why?

Comment: If its an interview question, I would say you have know when to ask more questions, because interviews don't always know what they are talking about or are being obtuse to see if you can draw out what the real requirement is from a customer who doesn't.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Actually this question was asked to me in an interview, as I already tagged it under same category...please try to think in synchronisation context if it is possible.

Comment: Like a said, some times you are given a solution to a problem which is a bad idea. (Often on StackOverflow ;) The interviewer could be asking you; What do you do in that situation? My answer would be to find out what the real requirement is which can be solved and explain why the proposed solution is a bad idea.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yes I cross verified it but he told me the same requirement that he want to stop the first thread as soon as second enters into the second method...

Comment: race conditions don't have a unique solution , it really depends on the context.

Comment: Is the requirement that exactly zero or *one* threads can be busy in method "A," or do you mean that *any* number of threads can be busy in method "A" and should be "stopped" by activity in method "B"? That cardinality makes a difference in the potential solutions. Also, what do you mean by "stopped?" Interrupted, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer your question literally and show you why its a bad idea.

```
private Thread lastThread;

public void transferMoney(Account account, Account account2, int amount) {
  Thread t = lastThread;
  if (t != null)
      t.stop(); // so another thread running this immediately on a random line.
  lastThread = Thread.currentThread();
  // lastThread could die here
  if (account1.withdrawn(amount)) { // the withdraw was successful
      // lastThread could die here
      account2.deposit(amount);
  }
  // lastThread could die here
  lastThread = null;
}
```

This code is flawed in many ways, but if two threads enter this method the first thread could be stopped.  However it could leave account1 missing money which was not transferred to account2. (or worse)

In short, it makes no sense to have one thread kill another thread, in fact you so to great lengths to AVOID this, so encouraging it in any way is bad idea.

Comment: pstt, you made lastThread final. Pretty sure you didn't mean to do that.

Comment: @Peter this is your implementation..there could be a possibility that we need this kind of scenario. Thanks for your answer buddy

Comment: @peter Can i have your email id?

Comment: @SunnyGupta You can always ask questions on this forum. (I don't know everything ;)